# DAX Sum Quantity by Month per Product in a different table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following columns in Power BI:

1. "**full updated ALL PARTS** " table: Order Quantity; Month; Vendor Name; TAT; Material Number
2. "**Part Numbers**" table: Part Number; Vendor

I'm trying to create a Line and Stacked Column chart where column values are Total Quantities by Part Number per Month, column series are Month, and line values are Average TAT by Part Number

Because of that, I want to calculate Total Order Quantity by Month per Part Number.

I came up with this:

```
Sum amount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'full updated ALL PARTS (2)'[Order Quantity] ),
    DISTINCT ( 'Part Numbers'[Part Number] )
)
```

However, I don't know how to filter the result by month. Or maybe I approached the problem wrong. Please let me know what would you do in this case. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want this to show in a visual or are you trying to do a calculated column or what? Also, what is the purpose of the `DISTINCT` line here?

Comment: Hi, I want to create a measure. The reason I put DISTINCT there was because I wanted to know the total quantities of only the part numbers in the "Part Numbers" table and see if they have any volumes in the "full updated ALL PARTS". Let me know if it's still not clear for you. Thank you!

Comment: Are you going to use the measure in a visual that has the month as part of the filter context? For example, a matrix with `Month` on the rows or columns?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes! I actually want to create a line and stacked column chart where column series are months, column values display Total Order Quantity by Part Number per Month, and line values represent Average TAT per Part Number per Month. I'll add more info in the description. Sorry for this inconvenience!

Comment: If you're doing that, you I don't think you'll need filters in your total measure since each value will be calculated within its filter context that includes `Month` and `Part Number`. If this isn't working, please show what you are currently getting and some description of the desired result to compare this to.